# Display the number of unseen comments on a page since the user last visit

Tags: comments, users, javascript

The community is private and it has several pages /wordpress /design /etc . When users go to those pages the only thing they can do is to comment.

Now, what I am trying to do, Idk if possible, but if it is I need some directions/hints on what too search for.

http://jsfiddle.net/melbourne/uPqBe/4/

Instead of those numbers I want to display like the title says, the number of lastest comments since the current user visited those pages.

I thought of using localStorage/cookies but then if the user decides to login from somewhere else, that won't do the job, in others words I dont have a clue on where to go from here.

Any suggestions would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the data in the user meta as an array of post-id -> comment count at last visit and then simply count the comments since that date, for example

```
function get_user_comment_count_since_last_visit($user_id ,$post_id){
    //only do this for logged in users
    if ($user_id <= 0 ){
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * get last comment count for a post id from user meta if set
     * and if not set then we define zero
     */
    $user_last_visit = get_user_meta( $user_id,'_last_visit_',true);
    if (!isset($user_last_visit[$post_id]) || $user_last_visit[$post_id] < 0)
        $user_last_visit[$post_id] = 0;

    /**
     * get current comment count of the post
     */
    $comments_count = wp_count_comments( $post_id);

    /**
     * get the amount of added comment since last visit
     * and update the user meta for next visit
     */
    $user_last_visit[$post_id] = $comments_count->approved -  $user_last_visit[$post_id];
    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_last_visit_',  $user_last_visit);
    return $user_last_visit[$post_id];
}
```

and to use it you call it with the page id and user id of the current logged in user.

Comment: I started to write an answer which is as of now twice as longer - very elegent (and fast!) :)  - copy & save to my snippet collection!

Comment: This is the first thing that I thought of but I don't like that it requires a database write every time that function runs which is presumably every time that page loads. I thought that should be mentioned but given the OP's implied condition that this not be done with cookies, I don't see another alternative.

Comment: You could add a date comparison check before updating the user meta...

Comment: @SagiveSEO what would you been comparing if its been at least a minute?still writing the database once a a minute its bad news. Also if you want to increase it to 10 minutes to reduce db wr, then you're better off recording when they login in anyways and showing them comments since the last time. The answer is what I wanted and is correct but the more I think about it, the more I think I will switch to cookies.

Comment: it is a drain on resources...however - i got a live example where i do use some closed wp installation to alert users of changes that were done across site when even they happen and it works great but i guess it all depends on the volume so no argument from me.